# Remote access between two android devices

Tags: android, remote-access

I have developed a financial management application in Android, using Phonegap , cordova and jquery mobile. I want to add a new functunality in it, the functionality is when a customer is facing difficulty while using the application,a customer representative can take control of the application on customer's device through his android device, to help the customer, just like one Android device accessing other android device. So is there any plugin or API I can use in my application which can provide the desired functionality to me?
  More precisely I am looking for the peer to peer access without any interimidiate server, i.e. one android device should be able to take control of another android device directly. Using internet.

Comment: This would be very difficult. I wouldn't recommend going that way.

Answer (score 1):

For p2p connections http://developer.android.com/training/connect-devices-wirelessly/wifi-direct.html

Remote control is a bit complex. Maybe this'll help you http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html